# Locate devices in given area with Google Maps and send push to phone via. app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ibeacon

Is it possible to setup smaller areas with Google Maps in your own app and send push messages to the users that have your app if they get inside this area in Google Maps?

Eg.
We have an app and have displays in some smaller stores around the country. The customer enters the store or is close to the store and has his/hers phone with our app. The user now gets a push message via. our app to remember to enter our competition.

I have worked with Beacons and done this before, but now my colleague has heard that this is possible with google maps.

Solution was called Geofencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup it is done by Geofencing .Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

for more reference visit...
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jaimin. This looks like the solution we're looking for. Thanks again.